# What encoding Java uses to create string from give unicode data?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8, unicode-string

I am quite perplexed on why I should not be encoding unicode text with UTF-8  for comparison when other text(to compare) has been encoded with UTF-8?

I wanted to compare a text(= アクセス拒否 - means Access denied) stored in external file encoded as UTF-8 with a constant string stored in a .java file as

```
public static final String ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE = "\u30a2\u30af\u30bb\u30b9\u62d2\u5426"; // means Access denied
```

The java file was encoded as Cp1252.

I read the file as as input stream by using below code. Point to note that I am using UTF-8 for encoding.

```
 InputStream in = new FileInputStream("F:\\sample.txt");
        int b1; 
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            b1 = in.read();
            if (b1 == -1)
                break;
            bytes[i++] = (byte) b1;
        }

        String japTextFromFile = new String(bytes, 0, i, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Now when I compare as

```
System.out.println(ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE.equals(japTextFromFile));  // result is `true` , and works fine
```

but when I encode `ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE` with UTF-8 and try to compare it with `japTextFromFile`  result is `false`.  The code is

```
String encodedAccessDenied = new String(ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE.getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

System.out.println(encodedAccessDenied .equals(japTextFromFile));  // result is `false`
```

So my doubt is why above comparison is failing, when both the strings are same and have been encoded with UTF-8? The result should be `true`.

However, in first case, when compared different encoded strings- one with UTF-16(Java default way of encoding string) and other with UTF-8 , result is `true`, which I think should be `false` as it is different encoding ,no matter text we read, is same.

Where I am wrong in my understanding? Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your default character set? What do you think `ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE.getBytes()` does?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis :  default character set - I need to check in my office  workstation so not sure. It will return bytes array with java platform default charset(as explained by java doc).

Comment: Do you have a line feed in sample.txt?

Comment: If you're using Java 7, you might want to consider using the super handy `Files.readAllLines()` method like: `Files.readAllLines("F:\\sample.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-8")).get(0)`

Answer (score 2):

`ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE.getBytes()` does not use UTF-8. It uses your platform's default charset. But then you use UTF-8 to turn those bytes back into a String. This gets you a different String to the one you started with.

Try this:

```
String encodedAccessDenied = new String(ACCESS_DENIED_IN_JAPANESE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),StandardCharsets.UTF_8
);

System.out.println(encodedAccessDenied .equals(japTextFromFile));  // result is `true`
```

Comment: Note that doing this `new String(utf8Bytes, utf8charset)` dance is basically a no-op.

Comment: @Jonathan :Yes, I am getting your point. Simply by encoding with UTF-8 while reading through 'String.getBytes("UTF-8")' might result in expected output. Need to test this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is put all static texts into a text file encoded with UTF-8. And then read those resources with `FileReader`, setting encoding parameter to "UTF-8"